# Using Dojo MD5 with xPages

Tags: dojo, xpages

I try to get this code work. And i always have this error : "[ReferenceError] dojox not found". Domino R9.0.1 with xPages.

Thanks

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" dojoForm="true"
 dojoParseOnLoad="true" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

 <xp:this.resources>
  <xp:dojoModule name="dojox.encoding.digest.MD5"></xp:dojoModule>
 </xp:this.resources>
 <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
  <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var d=dojox.encoding.digests.MD5("test");
d;}]]></xp:this.value>
 </xp:text></xp:view>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems. One is the dojoModule, this should be `dojox.encoding.digests.MD5`. Second you're computing a value using client javascript (Dojo) inside server side script. That will not work.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish but you could make it work like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    dojoParseOnLoad="true">

    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dojox.encoding.digests.MD5"></xp:dojoModule>
    </xp:this.resources>


    <xp:inputText id="inputText1"></xp:inputText>


    <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
    var d=dojox.encoding.digests.MD5("test", dojox.encoding.digests.outputTypes.Hex);
    dojo.byId("#{id:inputText1}").value = d;
})]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:view>
```

It will add the MD5 hash inside the inputbox that you can connect to any datasource.

Comment: marbat23, remember to accept the answer if it helped you